# What shape is homeomorphic to a sphere attached with a handle and a cross cap?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, low-dimensional-topology

The classification theorem for closed surfaces states that a orientable closed surface is homeomorphic to a sphere with m handles with m >= 0; while a nonorintable closed surface is homeomorphic to a sphere with n cross caps with n > 0.

Then, what surface is homeomorphic to a sphere with both a handle and a cross cap? Is this surface orientable? What is its Euler number?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up Dyck's theorem.

Comment: The sphere with three crosscaps is homeomorphic to a sphere with one torus and one crosscap. So more generally, a sphere with $n$ crosscaps and $m$ tori is equivalent to one with $n+2m$ crosscaps and no tori.

Comment: the genus three non orientable surface: it is like a torus with a crosscap

Comment: compare: https://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces/dyck/dyck.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dyck's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Monoid_structure)  shows that although a torus by itself can't be turned into crosscaps, if there is *another* crosscap around you can send the torus through it and turn it into two crosscaps, so  the sphere with one torus and one crosscap  is homeomorphic to a sphere with 
three crosscaps, and more generally, a sphere with $n$ crosscaps and $m$ tori is equivalent to one with $ n+2m $ crosscaps and no tori.